# C# - Console.Beep does not work on Windows Vista

Tags: c#, console-application, beep

When I tried `Console.Beep()` on Win Vista (64bit), it just does not work. The speaker itself is OK, when the PC starts, it beeps.
Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is it 64 bit Vista?

Console.Beep calls the API function [Beep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679277%28VS.85%29.aspx) which isn't supported on 64bit Vista.

Quote: *Windows Vista x64 and Windows XP 64-Bit Edition:  This function is not supported.*

You might be able to use [MessageBeep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680356%28VS.85%29.aspx) instead if it's ok with the beep coming through the speakers instead of straight from the motherboard. See [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.messagebeep) for how to call this from C#.

Comment: Apparently, they had to be told at first, before it become documented, see: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/356978/console-beep-doesnt-work-under-vista-64-bit?wa=wsignin1.0

Answer (score 2):

the Beep method is not supported on Vista/XP x64. I suppose you do have 64-bit OS?

Comment: I can confirm that it does work on 64 bit windows 7 (it will use the desktop speakers not the internal pc speaker.)

Comment: Scott, so if you call Comsole.Beep your sound card plays it?

Comment: @Petr: If you prefix a previous commenters name with an `@` they'll get notified that you left them a comment, otherwise @scott might not see it. (missed that Scott had already posted the link I had added to this comment so edited that out)

Answer (score 2):

As everyone else has posted pc speaker Beep is not supported in 64x of windows vista or XP and not at all in windows 7. Here is a blog posting from Microsoft explaining why

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2010/01/04/what-s-up-with-the-beep-driver-in-windows-7.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, the `Console.Beep()` does not work on 64 bit windows as [the documentation states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fe3hdb1.aspx). Instead, you can use the following statement that issues a beep (but not through the Beep API):

```
// beep
System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
```

Workaround originally [found here at MSDN Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/356978/console-beep-doesnt-work-under-vista-64-bit?wa=wsignin1.0#).

Comment: This does not work. In the SystemSounds there is a Beep but is it not method. SoundsSystems namespace is uknown to my VS 2010

Comment: @Petr: `Beep` is not a method, it is a property of type `SystemSound` (without `s`). It has one method, `Play()`. I fixed the typo though. It works now.

Comment: Thanks. However it just plays the sound associated, no way how to change frequency etc. :(

Comment: @Petr: true. To do that, you can use normal Media methods to create your own sound, but that's a bit more work. As long as the underlying API doesn't work, you're quite stuck here, I'm afraid.